# R: How can I custum reorder a grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouped-bar-chart

I spent several hours searching for reordering a grouped bar chart on stackoverflow.com but I did not find the answer I was looking for.  I want to change the order of the bars and legend to print 'before', 'during' and 'after' in that order but R keeps printing the factors alphabetically like this 'after' before' during' and don't know how to fix it.

If someone can help me, I will be thankful!

This is the order R displays which I want to change.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("after","before","during","before","after","before","during","after","after","during", "during","after","before","during","before"),
variable = c("granny", "red del", "other", "golden", "star", "granny", "red del", "other", "golden", "star", "granny", "red del", "other", "golden", "star"),
value = c(34,66,7,12,99,35,66,82,55,48, 27,55,82,42,26))

df$time = as.factor(df$time)
df$variable = as.factor(df$variable)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = time)) + 
geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
theme_minimal() +
labs(x=' ', y=' ', title=' ') +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=20, face='bold')) +
theme_bw() + 
theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
plot.background = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

Comment: Of course. Many asked and answered questions on SO explain how to do that. Do some searching.

Comment: `df$time <- factor(df$time, c('before', 'during', 'after'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot will just order any character variable alphabetically if there is nor specified order. To specify order of factor levels, the easiest approach would be just to state the order of levels in the `factor` function.

```
df$time = factor(df$time,levels = c("before","during", "after"))
```

instead of

```
df$time = as.factor(df$time)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it worked!  To be honest, my code was originally in wide format but when I converted to long format, R converted time to a factor which seemed correct to meso I left it and tried other solutions online but I guess they cannot override the initial factor assignment?